# javascript query string encoding

Tags: javascript, html

why does encodeURI and encodeURIComponent encode spaces as hex values, but then I see other encodings using the plus sign?  there's something i'm obviously missing.

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "hex values as spaces"? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Pekka spaces " " turn into "%20" for instance

Comment: That would be a space encoded as a hex value, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC `+` is a form encoded , while `%20` is a standard URI encoding.

They are interchangeable, so don't worry about which one you use.

Comment: a nice reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: A note about being "interchangeable": they are interchangeable for use as locations and data-passing to servers, however they will not be equivalent strings (obviously), which means that when using them for encoding/decoding cookie name-value pairs, care must be taken to encode/decode properly.

Answer (score 0):

"+" is allowed as a substitute for spaces, however there are lots of other special characters that need escaping as hex values (in the form %nn). Presumably the authors of encodeURI and encodeURIComponent decided to use hex values for everything including space, since it made their code simpler and they didn't think the extra two characters for each space in a uri was really that important.

Answer (score 0):

Look here for a discussion of the differences between escape, encodeURI, and encodeURIComponent, with interactive examples for all three of them:

http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

To summarize:

> The `escape()` method does not encode
>   the `+` character which is interpreted
>   as a space on the server side as well
>   as generated by forms with spaces in
>   their fields. Due to this shortcoming
>   and the fact that this function fails
>   to handle non-ASCII characters
>   correctly, *you should avoid use of
>   `escape()` whenever possible*. The
>   best alternative is usually
>   `encodeURIComponent()`.
>
> `escape()` will not encode: `@*/+`
>
> Use of the `encodeURI()` method is a
>   bit more specialized than `escape()`
>   in that it encodes for
>   [URIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/)
>   as opposed to the querystring, which
>   is part of a URL. Use this method when
>   you need to encode a string to be used
>   for any resource that uses URIs and
>   needs certain characters to remain
>   un-encoded. Note that this method does
>   not encode the ' character, as it is a
>   valid character within URIs.
>
> `encodeURI()` will not encode:
>   `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`
>
> Lastly, the `encodeURIComponent()`
>   method should be used in most cases
>   when encoding a single component of a
>   URI. This method will encode certain
>   chars that would normally be
>   recognized as special chars for URIs
>   so that many components may be
>   included. Note that this method does
>   not encode the ' character, as it is a
>   valid character within URIs.
>
> `encodeURIComponent()` will not
>   encode: `~!*()'`